# Form type request in Postman for API with nested serializers in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, postman, django-serializer

I need to pass the nested dictionary which is the mixture of text and file. I created the nested serializer to get the data from API request. What will be my request like in Postman?

**Request Structure:**

```
{
"type":"Large",
"category":[
{
"category_segment":"A", 
"category_features":["name", "size", "color"],
"action":["pack", "store", "dispatch"],
"category_image": **''' Category A Image File Here'''**
},
{
"category_segment":"B", 
"category_features":["name", "size", "color"],
"action":["pack", "store", "dispatch"],
"category_image":**'''Category B Image File Here'''**
}
]
}
```

**Serializer**

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    category_segment = serializers.CharField()
    category_features = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(default='Not Required'),default='Not Required')
    action = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
    image = serializers.FileField()


class ExtractionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.CharField()
    category_image = serializers.ListField(child = DataSerializer())
```